# Highcharts - TickInterval with datetime values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

From the highcharts docs : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickAmount

I can see tickInterval is not avilible for datetime axis, So my question is, is there a workaround to set the number of ticks labels in my xAxis?

I tried to play with it for a while, till now no success.

Comment: You're linking tickAmount, tickInterval does work on datetime axes.

Comment: but i dont want tickInterval... i want tickAmount... i am trying to find a workaround to get his functionality, i found some solution but not optimal

Comment: Easiest way to work around this is get the time difference between earliest/latest in milliseconds and then divide it by the tickAmount and use that as your tickInterval. But do update your question with what you really need, it's still saying that you need tickInterval.

Comment: The tickInterval works well, morever you can use i.e tickPositioner and apply as much ticks as you need. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3p2bfseu/

Answer (score 9):

**This answer is assuming you indeed want `tickInterval` and not `tickAmount`.**

I've successfully used `tickInterval` for `datetime` axes. It all depends on how much time you want between each tick mark.

For example, if you want to display a tick for each calendar year, you could do the following:

```
tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
// milliseconds * seconds * minutes * hours * days = 1 year
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

the value like this.dataMin / this.dataMax is seconds,not milliseconds

```
tickPositioner: function(){
    var positions = [] ;
    var min = Math.floor(this.dataMin) ;
    var max = Math.floor(this.dataMax) ;
    var gap = (max - min) / (60*60*24*30) ;
    var d = new Date(this.min*1000);

    for(i=0;i < (gap+1);i++){
        var d2 = new Date( d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getMonth()+1+i)+'-01');
        positions.push(d2.getTime()/1000);
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.