# how to display 24 hours in xAxis on highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to show hours in 24 hrs format on xAxis, following are the codes I am using -

```
 xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 3600 * 24,
        type: 'datetime',
        min: Date.UTC(2020, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        max: Date.UTC(2020, 7, 1, 23, 59, 59),
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day: "%H:%M"
        },
        //tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
          overflow: 'justify',
          style:{
            color:'#46474a'
          }
        },
```

but the interval is not working properly, I need the interval to be 1 hour, currently it is showing hours in 30 mins of interval.

[image]

**update -** I got to know more about time interval with this link -

[Highcharts - TickInterval with datetime values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076540/highcharts-tickinterval-with-datetime-values)

```
tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
// milliseconds * seconds * minutes * hours * days = 1 year
```

And changed the `tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60` , hours are showing proper now but the chart is still not plotting.

[image]

I tried different **tickInterval** but it is not working. Please help, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Sachin Vairagi, Could you provide me with an example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Change out your dateTimeLabelsFormat for just this

```
labels: {
    format: '{value:%H:%M}'
}
```

You can try removing tickInterval as well and see if you prefer the automatic style.

Comment: If I remove tickInterval and update format as you suggested then it is showing time interval of 3 hrs like 00:00 03:00 06:00